Derangements of LEMMA with Inclusion/Exclusion
I'm trying to use Inclusion/Exclusion to find the number of derangements of $\text{LEMMA}$. Recall that a derangement of a word is an arrangement of the letters in which
no letter is in the correct position.
What I've done so far is look at the permutations of $\text{LEM}_1\text{M}_2\text{A}$.
If I set

$A_1$ = the set of arrangements with $\text{L}$ in the correct position,
$A_2$ = the set of arrangements with $\text{E}$ in the correct position,
$A_3$ = the set of arrangements with $\text{M}_1$ in the correct position,
$A_4$ = the set of arrangements with $\text{M}_2$ in the correct position,
$A_5$ = the set of arrangements with $\text{A}$ in the correct position.

I have that

$|A_1|=|A_i|=4!=24$ for $2\leq i\leq 5$.
$|A_a\cap A_b|=3!=6$ for all possible (unordered) pairs $(a,b)$.
$|A_a\cap A_b\cap A_c|=2!=2$ for all possible (unordered) triples $(a,b,c)$.
$|A_a\cap A_b\cap A_c\cap A_d|=1!=1$ for all possible (unordered) quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$.
$|A_a\cap A_b\cap A_c\cap A_d\cap A_e|=1$ for all possible (unordered) quintuples $(a,b,c,d,e)$.

Now using the I/E formula I have $$5(24)-10(6)+10(2)-5(1)+1=76$$
Note there are, in total, $\frac{5!}{2!}=60$ permutations of $\text{LEMMA}$.
Here's where I think I'm going wrong: I have divided $76$ by $2!$ to remove double counts of the $\text{M}$s through $\text{M}_1$ and $\text{M}_2$ to get $38$ and then have subtracted from $60$ to get $22$.
I then wrote a program to check if my answer was correct. It seems to be $12$. Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

The problem with your reasoning is that if you put M1 in place of M2 and M2 put somewhere else, you count it as good permutation, which in reality is not. You must add the doubled number of such permutations (doubled since M1 can go to M2’s place or vice versa; this number is actually $D_4=9$) to $76$ and add the number of derangements where M1 and M2 swap places (this is easily calculated as $D_3=2$). Thus you get the answer $$60-\frac{76+2\cdot9+2}2=12.$$
Consider the following, actually inclusion-exclusion, reasoning. I think, it is more simple. And it works nicely for larger words.
There are $\binom32$ ways to choose two positions for letters M. They take places of some other two letters (we will call them letter of type $1$). Hence these two letters of type $1$ will change their places in permutation, they are safe. There is also $5-2-2=1$ letter (of type $2$), which should change its place.
There are $3!$ permutations of letters of types $1$ and $2$. And there are $2!$ ways to arrange these $3$ letters so that the letter of the type $2$ remains in its place. Hence, there are
$$3!-2!=4$$
allowed permutations of letters of types $1$ and $2$. The answer is then $$\binom32\times4=12.$$
